# Nuxtjs регионы в URL адресе

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Есть некий сайт на Nuxtjs, в данный момент без функционала городов.
Хочу внедрить данный функционал, и чтобы к урлам добавлялся префикс выбранного города

Пример:
https://site.ru/msk/catalog/ и тд тп
https://sitre.ru/spb/catalog и тд тп

Каким образом можно менять урлы? чтобы они продолжали работать как и раньше, только с добавленным префиксом? Не прошу готовый код, просто подскажите куда двигаться, или подскажите чуть-чуть логики как такой функционал строить. Дальше я сам разберусь) Спасибо

p.s По умолчанию, если город не выбран, то никаких префиксов быть не должно

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял - речь идет о динамических роутах.
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing